# Drawing a graph with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, graphs

How would one draw a f(x)=1/x graph in tikz?

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have a look at `pgfplots` and the countless examples out there.

Comment: If my solution solved your problem (and I think so according to your newer question), consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}%
    [
        grid=major,  
        x=5mm,
        y=5mm,
        xtick={-5,-4,...,5},   
        xmin=-5,
        xmax=5,
        xlabel={\tiny $x$},
        axis x line=middle,
        ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
        tick label style={font=\tiny},
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=5,
        ylabel={\scriptsize $f(x)=1/x$},
        axis y line=middle,
        no markers,
        samples=100,
        domain=-5:5,
        restrict y to domain=-5:5
    ]
    \addplot[thick,samples=400] (x,{1/x});
 \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this (just adjust the domain to your needs). For further customizations look for `pgfplots`.

[image: smooth plot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[smooth,domain=0:1] {1/x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```